# How to use variable from a Controller in a Directive link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I want to be able to use the variable "videoUrlId" from the controller 'useSpreadsheetData' below in my directive 'meetings'. How can I do this? I have looked at require but could not get it to work.

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('useSpreadsheetData', ['$scope', '$sce', 'getSpreadsheetData',      
function($scope, $sce, getSpreadsheetData){
for(var x in videos) {
      if(videos[x].switchValue) {
        var videoUrlId = videos[x].videoUrl;
        $scope.videoUrlId = videoUrlId;
        break;
      }
    }
};
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('meetings', [ 'getCalendar', '$timeout', '$window',  
function(getCalendar, $timeout, $window){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/meetings.html',
    controller: 'useSpreadsheetData',
    link: function(scope){
    //Use videoUrlId variable here
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: You can access `videoUrlId` in your link function with `scope.videoUrlId`

Comment: In order to share data between *directives* and *controllers* or *controllers* and *controllers*, you should use *Services*. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219403/angularjs-passing-variable-to-scope-from-directive-to-use-it-in-controller-n) and  [this other one post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers).

Comment: @rob i get undefined when I access that variable in my link function.

Comment: is the code in your controller actually running? From what you've posted videos will always be undefined

Comment: @AndreaM16 My controller is already getting data from a service. Is there a way to get a variable from a controller and use it in my directive link function without making another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you attempted to use `require`, I have to assume the `meetings` directive will be a child element somewhere within the `useSpreadsheetData` controller, however without seeing your HTML, we can't be sure.

As you're not utilizing an `isolate scope`, your directive will **prototypically** inherit from the parent controller above itself, in this case `useSpreadsheetData`. As a result, we can simply get `videoUrlId` by accessing it via an interpolated expression: `{{videoUrlId}}`. Note the template in the `meetings` directive. It'll also be available within `link` or `controller` via `scope.videoUrlId` and `$scope.videoUrlId`, respectively.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/MZIgXEiku4Z2PLzl3apz

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="useSpreadsheetData">
  Controller: <code>videoUrlId = {{videoUrlId}}</code><br>
  Directive: <meetings></meetings>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.controller('useSpreadsheetData', function($scope) {

  var videos = [service call];

  for (var x in videos) {
    if (videos[x].switchValue) {
      var videoUrlId = videos[x].videoUrl;
      $scope.videoUrlId = videoUrlId;
      break;
    }
  }
});

app.directive('meetings', ['$timeout', '$window',
  function($timeout, $window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<code>videoUrlId = {{videoUrlId}}</code>'
    }
  }
]);
```

**Output**

```
Controller: videoUrlId = /1
Directive: videoUrlId = /1
```